# Intersection of two dense 1-codimensional subspace of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $Y, X_1, X_2$ are 1-codimensional subspaces of X.  $X_1, X_2$ are dense in X. Is $X_1 \cap X_2$ dense in X? Is $X1 \cap Y$ dense in $X$?

This is an exercise from Hahn-Banach theorem (chapter 3, Linear Analysis, Béla Bollobás). I tried to think $Y, X_1, X_2$ as kernels of linear functionals in order to apply Hahn-Banach theorem or hyperplane separation theorem but it doesn't work.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $X_1$ dense?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dense in $X$. I edited the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: $X_1 \cap Y$ cannot be dense  in $X$ in case $Y$ is closed.  Do you mean to ask whether $X_1 \cap Y$ is dense  in $Y$?